# How to control dependency injection in OSGi at runtime

Tags: java, dependency-injection, osgi, apache-felix

I'm trying to understand how to control dependency injection in OSGi (specifically Apache Felix as used in Adobe Experience Manager (AEM)). I have a servlet with an `@Reference` annotation on a field that references an interface -- in my case, it represents a secure document signing provider. I have an implementation class that implements the interface, and it's automatically injected into the servlet.

In the servlet:

```
@Reference(cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_UNARY)
private DocumentSigningProvider signingProvider;
...
URL redirectUrl = signingProvider.Sign(...);
```

and my implementation class:

```
@Component(metatype=true)
@Service
@Property(name = "service.ranking", intValue = 1000)
public class DocumentSigningProviderDocuSignImpl implements DocumentSigningProvider {
```

If I write a second implementation, I can control which one is injected via the `service.ranking` value -- highest number wins. If no ranking is declared on any of the implementations, the oldest wins.

So far, so good -- except that to change the values I need to recompile and redeploy. I need to control this at runtime, or via a configuration file that's tied to the environment or "runmode". I can't see how to do that.

Since the `@Component` declares `metatype=true`, `@Property` annotations *within* the class generate a control in the OSGi console's GUI. I can use that GUI to change values at runtime. But the `service.ranking` is declared in an `@Property` *on the class itself*, and it doesn't appear to generate a control in the GUI.

In addition, configuration files named after the class provide default values at runtime, and I can have a different config file for each environment or "runmode". This would work for me too; in one environment I can configure a mock implementation, and use a "real" implementation in another environment. But again, these config files seem to work for `@Property` declarations *inside* the class, but not *on* the class.

I've read a number of threads here about this subject but none touch on exposing `service.ranking` in the OSGi GUI or in config files.

Is there any way to control which class is injected without modifying, re-compiling and re-deploying source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In declarative services you can override any service property at runtime by providing a config for the component and setting the property.
So setting `service.ranking=1` or similar should actually work.

One thing to note. By default declarative services binds to the first available service and stays with it. So if you want to make sure a service with a higher ranking is used even if it comes later than the one with the lower ranking then you need this option on the consumer side:

```
@Reference(policyOption=ReferencePolicyOption.GREEDY)
```

This makes sure DS switches the service if a better one comes later.

If you want to be more specific what service to use on the consumer side you can also use a filter at runtime.

```
target.signingProvider=(myproperty=myvalue)
```

I have collected some more hints [here](http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2016/09/27/Some+hints+to+boost+your+productivity+with+declarative+services).

Comment: That sounds promising, but didn't work for me. I cloned my impl class & appended "2" to the name. I also copied the config file, checked the name matched the impl class, & added service.ranking="1" to the orig & service.ranking="2" to the new copy. When I ran I saw log entries from the copy, which had the higher rank. Then I switched the config values: I set the value of the original to "2" and that of the copy to "1". I re-built, redeployed & ran my app again, but the log entries still come from the copy, even tho it now has the lower svc ranking. To be sure I bounced my JVM, same results

Comment: the config looks like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="sling:OsgiConfig"
    docusign.hostname="demo.docusign.net"
    docusign.username="xxx"
    docusign.password="yyy"
    docusign.apikey="ABCD-12345abc-6de7-980f-a1b2-c3def4a56b7c"
    service.ranking="1"
/>
the docusign.xxx properties work fine, but the service.ranking seems to be ignored, because the same clas is injected regardless of the value.

Comment: One more thing -- I'm currently still using Felix SCR annotations, not the new standard OSGi DS annotations. The code we received in our project was all in Felix style, and I continued in that style. Is your advice only applicable to DS annotations, or should it work with SCR annotations as well?

Comment: Both annotation styles are translated to xml at build time. So at runtime it should work for both. You can use the webconsole to check if the service properties are applied. In your case the problem might be that service.ranking is not taken into account if a service is already bound.

Comment: Can't get it to work no matter what I do. In the web console I've unbound the services, deleted the configurations, and disabled the services and redeployed after each change and nothing I do makes the system pick the component with the higher service.ranking value. I'll accept this answer, but I'm surprised at how much trouble I'm having with this -- and also that it's not a widely-discussed topic; this is a major use case for DI. Maybe I need to start looking at using Maven to only deploy the class I want in a particular build/runmode.

Comment: Can you confirm that on the shell both services are present and they also have the service property service.ranking?

Comment: Yes, http://localhost:4502/system/console/status-scr shows:

12628=[com.tic.shared.core.services.impl.docusign.DocumentSigningProviderDocuSignImpl]
  Bundlecom.tic.shared.core (480)
  State=satisfied
  DefaultState=enabled
  Activation=delayed
  ServiceType=singleton
  Services=com.tic.shared.core.services.DocumentSigningProvider
  Properties=
    service.ranking=2
 (some properties not shown)

Comment: 12605=[com.tic.shared.core.services.impl.docusign.DocumentSigningProviderDocuSignImpl2]
  Bundlecom.tic.shared.core (480)
  State=active
  DefaultState=enabled
  Activation=delayed
  ServiceType=singleton
  Services=com.tic.shared.core.services.DocumentSigningProvider
  Properties=
    service.ranking=1

Comment: As you can see, Impl2 has rank ing=1, and Impl has ranking = 2 -- but when the class is called at runtime, it logs messages from Impl2, which has the lower ranking.

Comment: I am not sure if it makes a difference but can you try immediate=true for these services?

Comment: No, immediate=true didn't work either. And this is a brand-new installation -- we just upgraded from AEM 6.1 to 6.3, and this is the first time I've deployed our code to my local 6.3 environment, so there are no previous versions of the impl classes or configs in the repository. Impl2 with ranking 1 is still called even though Impl has ranking 2. BTW, thanks very much for your patience -- I really appreciate the help. I can't find many people who know the details, so it's really nice to get feedback from someone who does!